# Fluid sim is not working right; water forms a flat table with an object, creates a large gap

Tags: rendering

I am running a fluid sim, with the idea that I would create an animation with a box inside a small stream. I have carved a small stream path into a plane, and created a number of rocks by using the Particle-Hair system.

I have removed all double vertices and made the normals set to inside, the two things I have read cause a lot of fluid sim issues. Nonetheless, there is an issue. On the left side of the box, water will float high above the ground (set as an obstacle) then form a bridge in the air to the box using right angles and flat surfaces. I am unsure the reason for all of this. Any ideas? I tried moving the box farther away, the water still extends outward.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change an object to be part of a fluid simulation, a modifier gets enabled to said object.

This modifier has to be the first one.

This means if you got any mesh changing modifiers enabled they wont apply to the fluid simulation.

[image]

You need to apply anything before starting the render.

Comment: By apply do you mean click the apply button and permanently add the modifier, or just have it in the top of the chain? I went back and adjusted the fluid sim modifier so it was on top, still hasn't fixed my issue:(

Comment: I have created the rocks with the Particle-Hair system, if that helps

Comment: The modifier system works from top to bottom. Each modiefier gets visual appearent after the one above is done calculating

Comment: Okay, I see. Your rocks are particles. They have a shape applied to them but are bsicly shapeless points with no possible fluid colision physics. In the modiefier tab you can click on convert and have them each as a single object, They work as obstacles. The problem though. Due to Blender interal limits you cant have more than 256 individual objects with fluid physics enabled on them.

Comment: Got it, I'll tweak the scene and composition. Thanks !!